# Recursively calling the web service not executing completely

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium

I am working on Titanium Appcelerator to develop iphone application. I need to call a web service with different parameters about more than 1250 times. I have place the xhr.send() method inside the xhr.onload function. It working fine about 3-8 times but stop calling after that. No error or any issues displaying there. Please suggest.

```
  function(e){

var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

var Request = "<RefId>"+idArray[e.index]"</RefId>";
xhr.open("POST", url); 

xhr.setRequestHeader("WWW-Authenticate","Basic");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/xml", "charset=utf-8");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", Request.length); 
xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://example.com"); 

xhr.onload = function() {


    var doc = Titanium.XML.parseString(this.responseText);
    var type = doc.getElementsByTagName("studentName");

    Ti.API.info(type.item+';'+type.item.length);
    if(type.item.length<1){

        file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, "textfile.txt");

    }
    doc=null;
    type=null;


if(idArray.length>e.index){
//alert('Calling API');

var url="http://example.com";
var Request = "<RefId>"+idArray[e.index++]"</RefId>";   
xhr.setTimeout(2500);
xhr.open("POST", url); 
xhr.send(Request);

}

};    
xhr.onerror = function(){
    alert('Error')
};
xhr.send(Request);
```

}

Comment: sample code is attached here.

Answer (score 0):

I would try recreating the client each time not just calling send again

Comment: Any guess. what would be the reason of this?

Comment: Any response on this. Is that solvable?